# Redirect Output Back to File

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

I issued the following command, thinking it would take the contents of `foo.txt`, process it, and write it back to the original file. Instead when I opened the file, it was empty.

```
cat foo.txt | tr " " "\n" > foo.txt
```

What exactly is going on in this line, and how can I rephrase it to redirect output back to `foo.txt`?

Comment: You cannot read and write a file at the same time with pipes and redirections. So write to a temporary file, and as a final step copy it to the original file. Or use a tool that modifies a file "in place".

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/65304

Comment: Your redirect truncates the output file before `tr`  ever sees the file. You might try `tmp=$(mktemp); tr " " "\n" < foo.txt; mv -f $tmp foo.txt; rm -f $tmp`

Comment: Also, [`sponge`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the [moreutils package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/moreutils): `tr " " "\n" < foo.txt | sponge foo.txt`

Comment: @doneal24, a couple of things: 1) use `&& mv` instead of `; mv` -- this way, the original file does not get overwritten if the process fails; 2) $tmp no longer exists to `rm`, it has already been moved.

Comment: @dirkt More accurately you **can** read and write a file at the same time with pipes and redirections - that is the problem here - but the result is unlikely to ever be what you want.  Either the file you want is likely to get clobbered, or worse the content will loop round and round the pipe.  Eg: `echo hello hello hello > foo` `cat < foo >> foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection (`>foo.txt`) is done by the parent shell before the `cat` command runs, resetting the file to 0 bytes. Use something like

```
tr " " "\n" foo.txt >foo.new && \
  mv foo.new foo.txt
```

Also avoid the Useless Use of `cat`.

Comment: Using `mktemp` for the intermediate file is safer than a fixed file name.

Comment: @doneal24 `mktemp` would keep evil eyes out, but considering the threat environment, and the resulting data (same file, with spaces translated to newlines), is it worth the added complexity? I think not.

Comment: You killed an Almost Necessary Use Of Cat. `tr` reads stdin, writes stdout, no filename args exist. But `< foo.txt` is good.

Comment: “Also avoid the Useless Use of cat.” Why?